# How to make comments in logcheck files?

Tags: logging, log-files, regex

how can I add comments to logcheck ignore-rules?

Things I tried so far:

- **#** seems to match single # characters instead of starting a comment
- **empty lines** matches against everything
- **$** matches against everything
- **$^** seems to be an "impossible" regex, i.e. start of expression after end of expression

Is there a better way than starting lines with **$^** ?

Is it guaranteed that lines starting with **$^** will never match? What about performance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of [logcheck 1.1.9.1](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=148964) (which was released in 2002), blank lines, lines that only consist of [`[:space:]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) characters, and comments (lines that begin with `#`) are filtered out before the rule files are passed to egrep.

This is mentioned in passing in the "WRITING RULES" section of [`docs/README.logcheck-database`](http://logcheck.alioth.debian.org/docs/README.logcheck-database), which is available in `/usr/share/doc/logcheck-database/README.logcheck-database.gz` on my system (Ubuntu 12.04, logcheck 1.3.14):

> logcheck will preprocess [local rule files] to eliminate dangerous blanks (since "egrep '' syslog" matches every line) and comment lines

It's also mentioned in this handy wiki article: "[Logcheck administration](http://wiki.bluelightav.org/display/BLUE/Logcheck+administration)":

> Filter files may have comment lines (beginning with #) and empty lines (containing only none or more space and tabs). These are ignored by logcheck.

It can be verified in the logcheck [source code](http://logcheck.alioth.debian.org/git.html) by searching for the `cleanrules` function, which writes rule files with these lines filtered out to a temporary directory before feeding them to egrep:

```
# pipe to cat on greps to get usable exit status
egrep --text -v '^[[:space:]]*$|^#' "$dir/$rulefile" \
    | cat >> "$cleaned/$rulefile"
```